# Berggren's Pythagorean ascent - reference request

Tags: reference-request, pythagorean-triples

Looking for an online resource and/or disambiguation for the following reference on Pythagorean triples:

B. Berggren, Pytagoreiska trianglar, Tidskrift f¨or Element¨ar Matematik, Fysik och Kemi 17 (1934), 129–139

Online search on https://scholar.google.com yielded a number of citations, but no links to original paper. Any pointers/help is appreciated.

This was prompted by the following ambiguious mentions: (**Emphasis** added)

Keith Conrad, in this paper (https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/linmultialg/descentPythag.pdf) mentions:

> In 1934, Berggren [3] showed **every primitive Pythagorean triple $(a, b, c)$ with $b$ even**
> can be generated from the triple $(3, 4, 5)$ by a $3$-fold
> ascent using the three matrices...

Wikipedia (as on Sep 29, 2022) states the following on the [Pythagorean Triples article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Parent/child_relationships)

> By a result of Berggren (1934), **all primitive Pythagorean triples** can
> be generated from the $(3, 4, 5)$ triangle by using the three linear
> transformations $T1, T2, T3$ below, where $a, b, c$ are sides of a triple:...

My understanding is that both Conrad's paper and the Wikipedia article are describing the same process of generating primitive triples.

Is the result true for *all primitive Pythagorean triples* or only *primitive Pythagorean triples with even $b$*?

Comment: Conrad mentions in the opening paragraph of his paper:

"In any primitive Pythagorean triple one of a and b is odd and the other is even: if a and b were both even then c would be even, violating primitivity, and if a and b were both odd then $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 \equiv 1 + 1 \equiv  2 \mod 4$, which has no solution. Since the roles of a and b are symmetric, we will assume throughout that **$b$ is even**."

Comment: In all Pythagorean triples, side $\space b\space$ isa multiple of $\space 4\space$ so it must be even whether it is primitive or imprimitive.

Comment: @poetasis: Yes, got that after re-reading the first paragraph. The only pending item is the online resource reference request.